# Using VideoWriter's mp4 format in CentOS

Tags: matlab, centos

In MATLAB there is the VideoWriter class and one of the `Profiles` that can be used is `MPEG-4`. I wanted the `mp4` format instead of the default `avi` so I used the following code on my centOS computer:

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('test.mp4','MPEG-4');
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Error using VideoWriter (line 168) The specified profile is not valid.
```

I knew the `'MPEG-4'` profile is valid so I then tried the same code on Windows and it worked. Is the problem that I am using centOS and if so is there a way to use the mp4 profile.

Comment: Do you know if the profiles are plugins or compile-time features? Have you checked for additional matlab packages in the CentOS repositories and/or the EPEL repository?

Comment: They are complie-time features and no, I did not check for additional packages but I believe from more research that it has to do with centOS not supporting the mp4 extension. I do not know how to resolve the issue as yet.

Comment: If the available packages don't support it then the best you can do is to build it yourself. Either via the CentOS SRPM (after modifying the spec file to undo whatever they did to disable that module or adding whatever is needed to enable it) or to build it yourself from scratch.